# Finding roots of a system of Integral equations with no closed forms in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I was able to solve for a root of a single integral equation, and I was able to figure out how to solve a simple system of equations, but I am struggling to put the two concepts together for a more complicated system.

I would like to use the MultiRoot function which uses the rootSolve library.

```
library(rootSolve)

a11 <- 1 #alpha_{11}
a12 <- 1 #alpha_{12}
a21 <- 1 #alpha_{21}
a22 <- 1 #alpha_{22}
b1 <- 2  #beta1
b2 <- 2 #beta2
d1 <- 1 #delta1
d2 <- 1 #delta2
g <- 0.5 #gamma

#defining the functions
integrand1 <- function(x,S) {b1*g/d1*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d1* x))*exp(-a11*b1*S[1]/d1*(1-exp(-d1*x))-a12*b2*S[2]/d2*(1-exp(-d2*x)))}
integrand2 <- function(x,S) {b2*g/d2*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d2* x))*exp(-a22*b2*S[2]/d2*(1-exp(-d2*x))-a21*b1*S[1]/d1*(1-exp(-d1*x)))}

#defining equation we would like to solve
intfun1<- function(S) {integrate(function(x)integrand1(x, S),lower=0,upper=Inf)[[1]]-1}
intfun2<- function(S) {integrate(function(x)integrand2(x, S),lower=0,upper=Inf)[[1]]-1}

#putting both equations into one term
model <- function(S) c(F1 ​= intfun1,F2 = intfun2)

#Using multiroot to solve
(ss <- multiroot(f = model, start = c(0,0)))
```

Gives me the following error:

```
Error in stode(y, times, func, parms = parms, ...) : REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'list'
```

---

---

Working up to this:
I was able to solve a single integral equation (with help)

```
a <-0.3 #alpha
b <- 2.5 #beta
d <-0.7 #delta
g <-1.1 #gamma

#defining the function, note S is free
integrand <- function(x,S) {b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d* x))*exp(-a*b*S/d*(1-exp(-d*x)))}

#defining equation we would like to solve
intfun<- function(S) {integrate(function(x)integrand(x, S),lower=0,upper=Inf)[[1]]-1}

#integrating the function from 0 to infinity
uniroot(intfun,c(0,1))
```

And I was able to figure out how to solve a simple system of equations:

```
model <- function(x) c(F1 = x[1]+ 4*x[2] -8,F2 = x[1]-4*x[2])
(ss <- multiroot(f = model, start = c(0,0)))
```

I also tried defining the code with S1 and S2 instead of S[1], S[2] but then I wasn't sure how to use the multiroot function, i.e. defining all my variables and then

```
#defining the functions
integrand1 <- function(x,S1,S2) {b1*g/d1*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d1* x))*exp(-a11*b1*S1/d1*(1-exp(-d1*x))-a12*b2*S2/d2*(1-exp(-d2*x)))}
integrand2 <- function(x,S1,S2) {b2*g/d2*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d2* x))*exp(-a22*b2*S2/d2*(1-exp(-d2*x))-a21*b1*S1/d1*(1-exp(-d1*x)))}

#defining equation we would like to solve
intfun1<- function(S1,S2) {integrate(function(x)integrand1(x, S1,S2),lower=0,upper=Inf)[[1]]-1}
intfun2<- function(S1,S2) {integrate(function(x)integrand2(x, S1,S2),lower=0,upper=Inf)[[1]]-1}

#putting both equations into one term
model <- function(S1,S2) c(F1 ​= intfun1,F2 = intfun2)

#Using multiroot to solve
(ss <- multiroot(f = model, start = c(0,0)))
```

But this gives the same error. I am also hoping to put a constraint on the solver so that it only gives values of S that are greater than 0. thank you!

Comment: Why do you need those values? Those are not the roots ie `intfun1(S1=0.129822, S2=0.103858)` is not close to 0. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Onyambu I got those on mathematica as the roots and I wanted to check them on R, I guess they are wrong. I would like to find the roots that make the expressions 0.

Comment: I am getting `S = c(0.06287756, 0.11885586)` try these out and see whether `intfun1(S)` is close to 0. or even if `integrate(function(x)integrand1(x, S),lower=0,upper=Inf)`  is close to 1. These to me seems to be the correct values as per the question. Note that this is only when we start searching from `0,0` otherwise there might be many local minimums. But still your values dont look like local minimums

Comment: @Onyambu Yes! it looks like those values of S1 and S2 give me integrals equal to  1.000027, so 1.000027-1 is about 0. How did you get those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
integrand1 <- function(x,S) {b1*g/d1*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d1* x))*exp(-a11*b1*S[1]/d1*(1-exp(-d1*x))-a12*b2*S[2]/d2*(1-exp(-d2*x)))}
integrand2 <- function(x,S) {b2*g/d2*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d2* x))*exp(-a22*b2*S[2]/d2*(1-exp(-d2*x))-a21*b1*S[1]/d1*(1-exp(-d1*x)))}

#defining equation we would like to solve
intfun1<- function(S) {integrate(function(x)integrand1(x, S),lower=0,upper=Inf)[[1]]-1}
intfun2<- function(S) {integrate(function(x)integrand2(x, S),lower=0,upper=Inf)[[1]]-1}

#putting both equations into one term
model <- function(S) intfun1(S)**2+ intfun2(S)**2
optim(c(0,0), model) # Note that different initial values(starting points) will produce diff results
$par
[1] 0.06287756 0.11885586

$value
[1] 1.45155e-09

$counts
function gradient 
      37       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: when you put both equations into one term,  why do we raise them both to the second power? **2 ? and does optim find the minimum? why do we use that instead of multiroot? is there a way to use multiroot?

Comment: @elcharlosmaster Raising to the second power means I am finding the sum of square errors. Ie  the same way we solve for the Least square parameters. Of course you could find the Sum Absolute Error etc. You choose your vest function to use. With regards to multiroot, i do not believe that is a base R function. It seems it is in another package. I do not have multiroot, so i used optim. You could use optimise/optimize. Yes there is a way to use multiroot. But i don't have access to the function so cant really tell.

Comment: is there a way to tell optim to only look for positive values of S_i ? What is a vest function?

Comment: @elcharlosmaster yes you can. Just ensure that the results is MA when any s<0

Comment: what does MA mean? How would I implement this? optim(c(0,0),model, MA) ?

Comment: @elcharlosmaster Sorry meant to say the results is `NA`. This should be the output of model function change the model function to include `if` statement. ie `model <- function(S) if(any(S<0))NA else intfun1(S)**2+ intfun2(S)**2` Now use this within the optim function